Using particle に with 今回/次回/前回
Is the particle NI required with these words?
姉は次回に連れてきます。
姉は次回連れてきます。
Are they both correct?

Yes, both are correct. When used adverbially in the sense of "on the next occasion" or "next time", 次回 and 次回に are interchangeable, but I think the former is more common.
This is unless 次回 is used as a noun; for example, you cannot drop に in 次回に延期する ("to postpone it until next time").
